# Regex to replace all instances of \r not followed by \n with \r\n

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

How can I replace `\r`'s with `\r\n` when the `\r` isn't followed by a `\n` using Regex ?

### The problem

I'm having problems with a text editor on Windows I'm creating in that line breaks are being added as \r. As a result they are not being read as line breaks when I open the file in Notepad.

### What I tried

I've tried looking everywhere (google, stackoverflow, etc) for this, but have been unable to find something that is *specifically* for what I'm after.

Everything I've tried so far does what I'm after the *first* time but it then keeps unnecessarily replacing `\r`'s even if they're followed by a `\n`.

For reference, this is the expression:

```
"\r(?!^\n)", "\r\n"
```

Comment: Cleaned up some of the verbiage and adjusted order and formatting, removing some superfluous wording.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use

```
\r(?!\n)
```

That is, remove the `^` start of string/line modifier from your `\r(?!^\n)` expression. The `\r` will match a carriage return and the `(?!\n)` will fail the match if there is an LF immediately to the right of it.

A [C# demo:](http://ideone.com/YYyg68)

```
var s = "Line1\rLine2\r\nLine3";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, "\r(?!\n)", "\r\n");
Console.WriteLine(res.Replace("\r","CR").Replace("\n","LF\n"));
// => Line1CRLF
//    Line2CRLF
//    Line3
```